# Can this python code be more efficient?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, time-complexity, python-itertools

I have written some code to find how many substrings of a string are anagram pairs. The function to find `anagram(anagramSolution)` is of complexity O(N). The substring function has complexity less than N square. But, this code here is the problem. Can it be more optimized?

```
for i in range(T):
    x = raw_input()
    alist = get_all_substrings(x)

    for k, j in itertools.combinations(alist,2):
        if(len(k) == len(j)):
            if(anagramSolution(k,j)):
                counter +=1

    counterlist.append(counter)
    counter = 0
```

The `alist` can have thousands of items (subsets). **The main problem is the loop. It is taking a lot of time to iterate over all the items. Is there any faster or more efficient way to do this?**

Comment: yes, exactly! I want to know if there is a way to optimize the iteration over the subset list.

Comment: So the question is basically: is there a faster way to iterate items than using a for-loop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the *anagram class* of a string to be the set of counts of how many times each letter appears in the string. For example, `'banana'` has anagram class `a: 3, b: 1, n: 2`. Two strings are anagrams of each other if they have the same anagram class. We can count how many substrings of the string are in each anagram class, then compute the number of pairs by computing `(n choose 2)` for every anagram class with n substrings:

```
from collections import Counter

anagram_class_counts = Counter()

for substring in get_all_substrings(x):
    anagram_class_counts[frozenset(Counter(substring).viewitems())] += 1

anagram_pair_count = sum(x*(x-1)/2 for x in anagram_class_counts.viewvalues())
```

`frozenset(Counter(substring).viewitems())` builds a hashable representation of a string's anagram class.

- `Counter` takes an iterable and builds a mapping representing how many times each item appeared, so
- `Counter(substring)` builds a mapping representing a string's anagram class.
- `viewitems()` gives a set-like collection of letter: count pairs, and
- `frozenset` turns that into an immutable set that can be used as a dict key.

These steps together take time proportional to the size of the substring; on average, substrings are about a third of the size of the whole string, so on average, processing each substring takes `O(len(x))` time. There are `O(len(x)**2)` substrings, so processing all substrings takes `O(len(x)**3)` time.

If there are `x` substrings with the same anagram class, they can be paired up in `x*(x-1)/2` ways, so the `sum` goes through the number of occurrences of each anagram class and computes the number of pairs. This takes `O(len(x)**2)` time, since it has to go through each anagram class once, and there can't be more anagram classes than substrings.

Overall, this algorithm takes `O(len(x)**3)` time, which isn't great, but it's a lot better than the original. There's still room to optimize this, such as by computing anagram classes in a way that takes advantage of the overlap between substrings or by using a more efficient anagram class representation.

Comment: `''.join(sorted(x))` is an easier to understand key?

Comment: @Anonymous: Perhaps. I consider them about equally understandable. Sorting has a slower asymptotic complexity, but `sorted` has a much better constant factor than `Counter`; I went for the better asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @user2357112 Wow! it sure works a lot faster now. It would really help me understand this if you could explain it a bit more.

Comment: @EkwinderSaini: More explanation added.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Time complexities added.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can wholly escape iterations for this problem but at least you can make the task at hand smaller by a factor of O(2^nC2/2^n).

You want to group substrings into their respective lengths before starting to iterate as you are adding a lot more cases to check.

The current method compares all pairs from a set, which takes 2^nC2 = comparisons. This is a huge number `(2^n)! / ((2^n-2)! * 2!)`.

If we first make a list of length 1-n substrings and then compare, we spend:

1. 2^n operations going through all substrings
2. nC2 operations going through substring of length 1
3. ...

That is, we are doing logarithmically better.

Edit: I realised that strings aren't sets and substrings aren't subsets, but that only affects the number of subsets and does not affect the main argument.

Comment: Substrings of length 1 are allowed. For example, in case of "abba", substring at indices 0 and 3 would be anagrams and the string has minimum length of 2.